# Does `ssh -D` proxy DNS request?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, openssh

Is DNS resolution tunneled to the other end when I use a SOCKS proxy created with `ssh -D`? I have read the manual, searched the Internet, and found no documentation relevant.

Comment: Yes. I use Firefox with it that way on a fedora 19 system

Comment: DNS resolution via Socks is up to the client (for example `curl` does only lookup DNS when specifying `socks5h://`, not only `socks5://`), maybe you have to explitly tell the client to lookup DNS via Socks. And yes, it does resolve DNS for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DNS resolution via Socks is up to the client. You have to explicitly tell the application to lookup DNS via Socks.

Name resolution is, just like connecting to a host, done by system calls like [`gethostbyname()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html) or [`getaddrinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html).

Unless instructed otherwise, a program may just use this function for name resolution which, of course, does not know about your tunnel.

For example curl does only lookup DNS when specifying `socks5h://`, not only `socks5://`.

Answer (score 5):

Your application can use the SOCKS proxy to resolve names as indicated
[here](https://serverfault.com/a/559626/193114).

If you are asking whether
[system wide lookups are tunnelled](https://superuser.com/questions/891701/system-wide-dns-lookups-over-ssh-tunnel), then the answer is *no*.

If you control the server side, then you could start a UDP-to-TCP proxy on your client as indicated
[here](https://superuser.com/questions/53103/udp-traffic-through-ssh-tunnel):

```
socat -T15 udp4-recvfrom:53,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:5353
```

And then forward the TCP connection via SSH to your server where you start a TCP-to-UDP daemon:

```
socat tcp4-listen:5353,reuseaddr,fork UDP:nameserver:53
```

You might, rightfully, frown upon that.  Fortunately, there is
[SSHuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle#readme) (e.g. mentioned
[here](https://superuser.com/a/638265/265964)).  There is a patch to forward DNS queries easily.

YMMV, but I have had success with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594319/shell-replace-cr-lf-by-comma
DNSSERVERS=$(nmcli d show | grep DNS | awk '{print $2}' | sed -e 'H;${x;s/\n/,/g;s/^,//;p;};d' )
sshuttle  \
    -vvv                \
     --dns-hosts ${DNSSERVERS}   \
    -r server   \
    254.254.254.254/32
```

Answer (score 2):

ssh -D works at (via man ssh)

> Specifies a local ``dynamic'' application-level port forwarding.
>     This works by allocating a socket to listen to port on the local
>     side

**Then what's a socket?** [via](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16311/what-is-a-socket)

> A socket is just a logical endpoint for communication. They exist on the transport layer. You can send and receive things on a socket, you can bind and listen to a socket. A socket is specific to a protocol, machine, and port, and is addressed as such in the header of a packet.

**And**

> Client have the ability to perform DNS lookups through socket proxy

[How-to with firefox mozilla-kb](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.proxy.socks_remote_dns)