# Examining /dev/log

Tags: linux, systemd, syslog, systemd-journald

`/dev/log` is the default entry for system logging. In the case of a systemd implementation (this case) it's a symlink to whatever `/run/systemd/journal/dev-log`. It used to be a receiving end of a unix socket handled by syslog daemon.

```
~$ echo "hello" > /dev/log 
bash: /dev/log: No such device or address
~$ fuser /dev/log
~$ ls -la /dev/log 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Aug 23 07:13 /dev/log -> /run/systemd/journal/dev-log
```

What is the clarification of the error that pops when you try to write to it and why isn't there a process holding that file (output from `fuser /dev/log` empty?

The logging does work normally on the system.

```
~$ logger test
~$ journalctl --since=-1m
-- Logs begin at Thu 2018-05-24 04:23:46 CEST, end at Thu 2018-08-23 13:07:25 CEST. --
Aug 23 13:07:24 alan-N551JM alan[12962]: test
```

Extending with comment suggestions

```
~$ sudo fuser /dev/log 
/run/systemd/journal/dev-log:     1   311
~$ ls -lL /dev/log
srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Aug 23 07:13 /dev/log
```

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Updated to make it clearer that the examples are from a systemd implementation.

Comment: what happens when you run `logger "test"`? Please add to the question.

Comment: Please, add to your question the output of `sudo fuser /dev/log` and `ls -lL /dev/log`

Comment: @andcoz Bravo, the `fuser` was a permission issue. Would of have totally missed that due to the silence.

Comment: Related: [How can I communicate with a Unix domain socket via the shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26715/how-can-i-communicate-with-a-unix-domain-socket-via-the-shell-on-debian-squeeze). You need to use something that uses `connect` rather than `open`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick If you convert your comment in an answer, I'll up-vote it.

Comment: Note the first character in ls output. It is a `s` (socket) not a `p` (pipe). You cannot use `open` based commands on it.

Comment: Related: [What is a socket?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193824/2634) in which it is explained why a socket differs from a pipe.

Comment: Feels like there is an answer in a combination of @andcoz and 
MarkPlotnick comments. Whoever makes that an answer will accept it.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Just notification for above :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To add some additional info to the accepted (correct) answer, you can see the extent to which `/dev/log` is simply a UNIX socket by writing to it as such:

```
lmassa@lmassa-dev:~$ echo 'This is a test!!' | nc -u -U /dev/log 
lmassa@lmassa-dev:~$ sudo tail -1 /var/log/messages
Sep  5 16:50:33 lmassa-dev journal: This is a test!!
```

On my system, you can see that the journald process is listening to this socket:

```
lmassa@lmassa-dev:~$ sudo lsof | grep '/dev/log'
systemd       1                 root   29u     unix 0xffff89cdf7dd3740       0t0       1445 /dev/log
systemd-j   564                 root    5u     unix 0xffff89cdf7dd3740       0t0       1445 /dev/log
```

It got my message and did its thing with it: (i.e. appending to the /var/log/messages file).

Note that because the syslog protocol that journald is speaking expects datagrams (think UDP), not streams (think TCP), if you simply try writing into the socket directly with `nc` you'll see an error in the syscall (and no log show up).

Compare:

```
lmassa@lmassa-dev:~$ echo 'This is a test!!' | strace nc -u -U /dev/log 2>&1 | grep connect -B10 | egrep '^(socket|connect)'
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)          = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 10) = 0

lmassa@lmassa-dev:~$ echo 'This is a test!!' | strace nc  -U /dev/log 2>&1 | grep connect -B10 | egrep '^(socket|connect)'
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 10) = -1 EPROTOTYPE (Protocol wrong type for socket)
```

Note I elided some syscalls for clarity. The important point here is that the first call specified the SOCK_DGRAM, which is what the /dev/log socket expects (since this is how the socket `/dev/log` was created originally), whereas the second did not so we got an error.

Answer (score 17):

I am summarizing the comments to a complete answer. Note that [@MarkPlotnick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/49439/mark-plotnick) was the first to point toward the right solution.

As you can see in `ls -lL` output, the file pointed by you link is a **socket**, not a regular file or a pipe.

```
~$ ls -lL /dev/log
srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Aug 23 07:13 /dev/log
```

Look at the first character of the output. That `s` means that the file is a socket.

You cannot use the redirection mechanism `>` of `bash` (or, AFAIK, any other shell) to write in a socket because the shell will try to *open* the file and `open` does not support sockets. See [man open](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open) for details.

You have to use a program that connects to a socket. See [man connect](https://linux.die.net/man/2/connect) for details.

As an example, you can use `netcat` or `socat` (see [How can I communicate with a Unix domain socket via the shell on Debian Squeeze?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26715/how-can-i-communicate-with-a-unix-domain-socket-via-the-shell-on-debian-squeeze)).

For the sake of completeness, you can use the redirection on pipes.

```
~$ mkfifo /tmp/fifo
~$ ls -l /tmp/fifo
prw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 27 ago 15.04 /tmp/fifo
~$ echo "hello" > /tmp/fifo
```

Look at the first character of the `ls` output. That `p` means that the file is a pipe.

Comment: Please also extend with your answer on why no processes were detected having a handle on the socked.

Answer (score -2):

You should verify /run/systemd/journal/dev-log, its permissions and who's using it.  You were checking a link.

Comment: That doesn't influence the results in any way. I mention it as being a link also in the question.

Comment: That's strange.  It would be interesting to know your distro.  On CentOS 7, /dev/log is a socket, used by the /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald process.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that "fuser /run/systemd/journal/dev-log" would show nothing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/256924)

Comment: @JeffSchaller  Better have a look at the edited question.  You'll find I did provide the answer.

Comment: I looked, and I still don’t see an answer. Could you spell it out more clearly?

Comment: He should have checked the file that the link pointed to,