# Understanding the term "socket" in the Unix/Linux context

Tags: socket, terminology

I understand that the term "socket" can mean two different things in the Unix/Linux context:

- A Unix socket; the interface between 2 or more processes.
- An IP socket; the interface between a process and 1 or more communicating services (or machines).

Is the general definition sums up in these two or there are is more to "socket" in our context?

Comment: CGI is not a socket.

Comment: Perhaps helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16311/117549

Comment: A socket is a generic endpoint for communication. See the `socket(2)` manual.

Comment: @Tomasz I removed that sentence, please consider omitting downvote if downvoted because of that.

Comment: I didn't downvote.

Comment: You can delete it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html

> ```
> int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> `socket()`  creates  an  endpoint  for  communication  and returns a file
> descriptor that refers to that endpoint.  The file descriptor  returned
> by  a  successful  call will be the lowest-numbered file descriptor not
> currently open for the process.

> The domain argument specifies a communication domain; this selects  the
> protocol  family  which will be used for communication.  These families
> are  defined  in  <sys/socket.h>.   The  currently  understood  formats
> include:

> ```
>    Name                Purpose                          Man page
> ```

```
   AF_UNIX, AF_LOCAL   Local communication              unix(7)
   AF_INET             IPv4 Internet protocols          ip(7)
   AF_INET6            IPv6 Internet protocols          ipv6(7)
   AF_IPX              IPX - Novell protocols
   AF_NETLINK          Kernel user interface device     netlink(7)
   AF_X25              ITU-T X.25 / ISO-8208 protocol   x25(7)
   AF_AX25             Amateur radio AX.25 protocol
   AF_ATMPVC           Access to raw ATM PVCs
   AF_APPLETALK        AppleTalk                        ddp(7)
   AF_PACKET           Low level packet interface       packet(7)
   AF_ALG              Interface to kernel crypto API
```

> ...

The above list is not comprehensive.  One of the others is `AF_BLUETOOTH` :-).

A socket is something you can call `sendmsg()` and `recvmsg()` on.  Messages are sent to / received from socket addresses.

There are further details, but they differ between socket types.  E.g. -

`SOCK_STREAM` sockets don't really care about messages.  They transport a stream of bytes, like a bi-directional equivalent of a unix pipe.  You can use the `write()` and `read()` calls without losing anything.  (Except for so-called "out of band" data.  This is [deprecated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6093) and was mostly used by `telnet`.)

For connection-oriented socket types including `SOCK_STREAM`, you can only send to / receive from one peer address per socket.  You must set this in advance using `connect()`.  Or on the other side, `bind()` to a specific address, and instead of receiving messages, you can receive *sockets*.  That is, you start listening by calling `listen()`, and then receive each connection by calling `accept()` which returns a socket.

The type `SOCK_SEQPACKET` is defined as connection-oriented (and reliable, in-order delivery), but otherwise [has conflicting definitions, even within the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54697729/799204).  And for [SCTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6458#section-3) it may receive connections *without* using the `accept()` call I described above.  So if you use a `SOCK_SEQPACKET` protocol, don't make too many assumptions about what that means. Look for information on the specific protocol implementation you are using instead.

Comment: The last 2 paragraphs (expect for the 1st sentence) are kind of bogus. Try harder ;-)

Comment: @pizdelect glossing over `connect()` was certainly a bit optimistic. In case I managed to mis-interpret RFC6458, it is probably better if I can strip that last paragraph down further... any better?